# How do I correct htaccess redirect to https

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

I have purchased SSL and installed it. It works, though I messed up something on htaccess. 
My first question is: how long does it take htaccess to take effect? Is it immediate?
Second: any idea why my redirect would turn into 
https://www.example.com/sample.com/page.php

I have changed the htaccess so many times, can somebody give me an idea how to redirect correctly any traffic to https://www.example.com

As of now, I have

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.php$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Dynamic configuration files are interpreted for every request, _if they are configured to be considered at all._ So they take affect immediately. They have a whole bunch of disadvantages over placing such rules in the real http servers host configuration, an obvious one is performance, but they get applied immediately.

Comment: Apart from that you question is unclear. Please tell us what the actual issue is currently.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I uploaded htacces and now, when somebody clicks on a google link gets
https://www.example.com/example.com/page.php
if the link is to the root, it works (https://www.example.com). Internal linking from the page works as well.

Comment: That redirection is _not_ caused by the rule set you posted. Either you actually have other rules than you posted or there are some additional rules you do not know about.

Comment: well, I am at the end. you guys think it is not htacces. called hosting, they have no idea. the only thing that changed is SSL and new blog, though WP is in a separate folder and should not have access to anything outside to the blog folder. right now, if I click on a link (video mailer) in Google (finally got myself on page #1) and I get to example.com/example.com/example.com/example.com/page.php. What would cause such loop?

Comment: Could it be that wordpress itself redirects? In addition to your redirection rules on the level of the http server?

Comment: I had to ask a former colleague to look into it and now it works... partially. This is the solution:

    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]

The problem is, that https://example.com does not redirect to https://www.example.com. 

Does anybody have a solution?